# C - strcat in for loop

Tags: c, console-application, strcat

I m writing a little C program and want to know why my output in the console is "0", "0" [...]? The output i expect is "ab", "ac", [...].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int i;
  int j;

  char string[] = "abc";
  char output[8];
  int length = size(&string[0]);

  for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
       for(j=0; j<length; j++){

       char a = string[i];
       strcat(output, &a);
       char b = string[j];
       strcat(output, &b);
       printf("%c\n", output);

       }
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `%s`, not `%c`. Please compile with `-Wall` to catch mistakes like this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but now it gives me back:
8a♥aa♥
8a♥aa♥a♥ba♥
8a♥aa♥a♥ba♥a♥ca♥
8a♥aa♥a♥ba♥a♥ca♥☺♥♥
8a♥aa♥a♥ba♥a♥ca♥c♥
8a♥aa♥a♥ba♥a♥ca♥a♥

Comment: @askdagee that's a lot of ♥love♥. Don't be afraid, it's Christmas.

Comment: hahahahahaha :D just want to share the love ;)

Comment: you need to initalize output - output[0] = 0;

Comment: What's value of...size(&string[0])?

Comment: `strcat` concatenates two strings,both of them,ending with a `\0`. You also try to store many characters into a buffer 8 elements long. All these leads to Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Remember, `strcat` concatenates strings to strings. All must be null-terminated. Passing `&a` and `&b` is undefined behavior because they are not null-terminated. Also, beware of [Schlemiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

Comment: `int length = size(&string[0]);`? Did you mean to use `int length = strlen(&string[0]);`?

Comment: its in another function ;) but yes it is exactly the same thing as u mentioned :)

Comment: @pm100 still hearts in the output.
FredLarson: without & it crashes.

Comment: Obviously you can't just drop the `&`. I'm saying you can only use `strcat` on STRINGS, not lone characters.

Comment: By enabling all warnings, the compiler will provide rapid feedback indicating many of the problems.  That information saves you time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mistake #1. You have not initialised `output[]` so `strcat()` will not validly find a `nul` terminator to append to.

```
output[0] = 0;
```

Mistake #2.  `strcat()` isn't the right way of appending chars anyway.

Mistake #3.  Your loop controls aren't right. See below.

Mistake #4. Your `length` is the size of a `char*` pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    char string[] = "abc";
    char output[8];
    int length = strlen (string);        // corrected

    for(i=0; i<length-1; i++) {          // amended loop
        for(j=i+1; j<length; j++) {      // amended loop
            output[0] = string [i];
            output[1] = string [j];
            output[2] = 0;               // string terminator
            printf("%s\n", output);      // uses string type not char
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
ab
ac
bc
```

Comment: `output` need not be 8 elements long

Comment: @CoolGuy that's true, and `main()` doesn't need arguments either.

Comment: You missed #5: passing `&a` to strcat when there's no reason to believe there's a '\0' anywhere in its vicinity.

Comment: Nice list of issue +1, but Mistake #1 is not enabling compiler warnings (or not using them).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker wasn't that my mistake #2?

Comment: @chux: Maybe we should call that Mistake #0. We are programmers, after all. 8v)

Comment: thank your very much for the answer. it was not exactly that what i m looking for (maybe had to explain the program output better), but i edited the loops like this:
for(i=0; i<length; i++) {         
for(j=0; j<length; j++) {
Et voila. It worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly what you are trying to do then the program will look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char string[] = "abc";
    char output[3];
    size_t length = sizeof( string ) - 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < length; j++ )
        {
            if ( i != j )
            {
                output[0] = string[i];
                output[1] = string[j];
                output[2] = '\0';

                puts( output );
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb
```

If your compiler does not allow to declare variables within the control statement of the loop then you can declare i and j in the beginning of the program.

```
size_t i, j;
```

If you want to include combinations like "aa" then you simply may remove the if statement withing the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
   char a = string[i];
   strcat(output, &a);
```

leads to undefined behavior since `strcat` expects a null terminated string in the second argument. Same thing applies to:

```
   char b = string[j];
   strcat(output, &b);
```

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
   output[0] = a;
   output[1] = b;
   output[2] = '\0';
```

Here's the updated `for` loop:

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
   for(j=0; j<length; j++){
      output[0] = a;
      output[1] = b;
      output[2] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", output);
           // ^^ use %s to print a string, not %c.
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `output[2] = '\0';` instead of `output[1] = '\0';`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `strcat` you must know that it expects a string not a character and there is an important difference, when you pass `&a` `strcat` thinks it is the address of a pointer to a string, and you should get most likely a `segmentation fault`, here I show your own code, modified to use `strcat` but you don't really need it for this task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    char string[] = "abc";
    int length = strlen(&string[0]);

    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        for(j= i + 1 ; j < length ; j++)
        {
            /* initialize output to 0 more importantly to have a terminating null byte */
            char output[3] = {0}; 
            /* 
             * create a string and initialize it with 2 char's 
             * - the first one, the one you want to append to output
             * - the second one is required by strcat, to mark the end of the string
             */
            char a[2] = {string[i], 0};
            strcat(output, a);

            /* same as above */
            char b[2] = {string[j], 0};
            strcat(output, b);

            printf("%s\n", output);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

you could do this without `strcat` unless you are trying to learn how to use `strcat`, this is an example of how to do it without `strcat`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    char string[] = "abc";
    int length = strlen(&string[0]);

    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        for(j= i + 1 ; j < length ; j++)
        {
            char output[3] = {string[i], string[j], 0}; 
            printf("%s\n", output);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```